# Multi-contact send SMS

Tags: android, sms, contacts

I need in my app send sms with contact number stocked in database.

For the moment I have there :

```
// Gets the context so it can be used later
public ButtonAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Message> list) {
    mContext = c;
    this.list = list;
}

// Total number of things contained within the adapter
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

// Require for structure, not really used in my code.
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

// Require for structure, not really used in my code. Can
// be used to get the id of an item in the adapter for
// manual control.
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Button btn;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        btn = new Button(mContext);
        btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 80));
        btn.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    }
    else {
        btn = (Button) convertView;
    }
    btn.setText(list.get(position).getTitre());

    if (btn != null) {
        btn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(v.getContext(), Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) v.getContext(), Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                        explain();
                    } else {
                        //demander l'autorisation
                    }
                } else {
                        ArrayList<Contact> numero;
                        String message = list.get(position).getContenu();

                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message);
                        smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(numero, null, parts, null, null);
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Vous venez d'envoyer le SMS : " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                return false;
                }
        });
    }
    if (btn != null) {
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("NON CONFIRME", list.get(position).getContenu());
            }
        });
    }

    // filenames is an array of strings
    btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
    btn.setId(position);

    return btn;

}

private void askForPermission() {
}

private void explain() {
    askForPermission();

}
```

And I want when the long clic has déclared the app send one sms has full contact stocked in my database.

```
                            ArrayList<Contact> numero;
                        String message = list.get(position).getContenu();

                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message);
                        smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(numero, null, parts, null, null);
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Vous venez d'envoyer le SMS : " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And my function in database :

```
    public static ArrayList<Contact> fetchAllNumero()
{
    ArrayList<Contact> mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor mCursor = bdd.query(TABLE_CONTACT, new String[]{COL_ID, COL_NUMERO}, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null)
    {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();

        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!mCursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setId(mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ID)));
            contact.setNumero(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(COL_NUMERO)));
            mArrayList.add(contact);
            mCursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return mArrayList;`

}
```

I dont say where make the display of the number and send full SMS.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What's the problem, exactly? Is something failing? Are you getting an Exception?

Comment: No, just I dont say How to make all contacts